# Could a Qt plugin change the UI created by main application?

Tags: c++, qt

I build a main Qt application to load model files(some kind of 3d models files like STL). And then I leverage a tree widget to show the loaded file's information. Then I build a Qt plugin to modify the loaded files.

Could I refresh the tree UI created in main application when I have completed editing file in the plugin? or, How could the plugin communicate with the main application,(for example tell main application that its data has been modified and it should refresh its UI )?

Comment: My first choice would be using signals and slots. If there are threads involved you may want to force a `Qt::QueuedConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use signal/slot solve the problem. First I build a common lib that are known by both main application and the plugin. Then I define a signal(which will be emitted when the UI should be changed) in the common lib and connect it with slot defined in the main application. After that, when I change the data by plugins I will let the common lib send the signal and the main UI could be changed.
Why not sending signal in plugins? Because I can't find a way connect signals in plugins with slot in main applications directlly. I hope that I have explained this well and there are other possible solutions.